# Как в Atmel Studio 6 разместить массив во flash памяти?

Tags: c, массивы, avr-gcc, atmel-studio, flash-память

Например, есть массив:

```
unsigned int tabz[] = {64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096};
```

В CodeVisionAVR, чтобы разместить этот массив во flash, надо написать так:

```
flash unsigned int tabz[] = {64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096};
```

В Atmel Studio 6 так нельзя.
Как в Atmel Studio 6 разместить массив во flash памяти?

Answer (score 3):

Для flash-памяти необходимо объявлять так:

```
const unsigned char Scena[4] PROGMEM = {1,2,3,4}
```

Обязательно указывать `const`, иначе пихает в ОЗУ!

Answer (score 1):

Пример для AVR GNU:

```
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <avr/pgmspace.h> 

uint8_t string[12] PROGMEM = 
{"hello world!"}; 
int main(void) 
{ 
 UDR0 = 
 pgm_read_byte(&string[10]); 
}
```